# Adding leading space to the text if substring is not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to align the text of a column in a table. For that I am trying to add a leading space to the text if the text doesn't have an Asterisk.

Here is what I have come up with (which is not working) :

```
$("table:eq(1) tr").find("td:eq(0)").text().index('*').css({ 'text-indent': '2pt'});
```

Is this a better way of doing if not pls suggest.

For example : data in the first columns now looks like

```
*S10054472  Active  50000       
11-506843   Active  95000       
12-59949    Active  12500       
12-5709     Active  12750       
*11-499979  Active  3232
```

should look like

```
*S10054472  Active  50000       
 11-506843  Active  95000       
 12-59949   Active  12500       
 12-5709    Active  12750       
*11-499979  Active  3232
```

Comment: might have an easier time just using `text-align: right` on that column...

Comment: that won't work because the text in the first column is not fixed size.

Comment: is this a table you're creating yourself?  Using JS at all would be overkill in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

### Script

```
$('table tr').find('td:first').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).text().match(/^\*/)
}).css('padding-left', '6px')
```

### Markup

```
  <table>
     <tr>
        <td>*S10054472</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>50000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>11-506843</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>95000</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

### Update

a less *intensive* filter function

```
$('table tr').find('td:first').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML[0] != '*'
}).css('padding-left', '6px')
```

Comment: why would an asterisk need to be case insensitive

Comment: @Ejay: My comment was out of line (and yes, I did not notice the g, just the i). Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be simple enough:

```
$('table td:contains("*")').prepend(document.createTextNode(' '));
```

It needs the `document.createTextNode` instead of a simple string with a space because jQuery's `.prepend()` expects a DOM element or a jQuery object.